Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese: resource eviction
In the Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese thread, there are useless resources, e.g.: (a) some guy wrote an app back in 2004, and it hasn't been maintained since, or (b) a predatory company copies some other Chinese-learning app to make quick money.  We need some way to evict this noise: we can't let it grow to infinity.
It's unrealistic to expect users to spend much effort documenting changes (after all, we're talking about low-quality resources); we all have more important things to do with our time.  Thus I propose a simple...
...Eviction policy

Users delete potentially useless resources from the page at will: we use our judgement.  (One or two at a time, please.)

We document it by editing this post below; only the date, name, and URL are needed.

If there's disagreement, we post an answer to this question.  Answers should include some evidence of usefulness, e.g. a link to web users saying they use this particular resource.  (I'm expecting little disagreement in most cases.)  We discuss, erring on the side of re-adding it if multiple users consider it useful.


I intend to use this in the upcoming days to indicate how it might work (and test it out).

Evicted resources

18 Sep 2020 HSK Locker
18 Sep 2020 Beginner Chinese
13 Sep 2020 Chinese Tutor Flashcards
13 Sep 2020 LearnChineseEZ


Recent related posts: What's the future for the "Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese" page? and Are requests for resources on-topic?
